# How to use ios 6 challenge in game centre

Tags: objective-c, xcode, game-center

Firstly,

I am fairly new to objective c / xcode dev so there is a good chance i am being a muppet.  I have written a few simple apps to try things and my most recent one has been testing the gamecentre classes / functionality.

i have linked ok to leaderboards and achievements - but i can't get challenges working.

I have added the following code.... which is in my .m

```
         GKLeaderboard *query = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] init];
          query.category = LoadLeaderboard;
          query.playerScope = GKLeaderboardPlayerScopeFriendsOnly;
          query.range = NSMakeRange(1,100);

          [query loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error)
           {NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"value < %qi", scoreint];
                NSArray *lesserScores = [scores filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];

               [self presentChallengeWithPreselectedScores: lesserScores];

           }
           ];
```

this code is basically taken from apple, just replacing the variable names....
this however gives an error on 
 [self presentChallengeWithPreselectedScores: lesserScores];

error Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'int64_t *' (aka 'long long *') is disallowed with ARC

LoadLeaderboard is defined as a string
scoreint is defined as integer, thought this may be issue as not int64_t but that does not seem to make a difference.

I am sure for someone who has any kind of a clue this is a straightforward fix.  But i am struggling at the moment.  So if anyone can be kind and help a fool in need it would be most appreciated

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't know your implementation of `presentChallengeWithPreselectedScores` method so I can't tell (although it looks like the method is taking a 64 bit integer and you're trying to feed it an array).

There are two ways to issue challenges:

**1** - This is the easier way - if you've successfully implemented leader boards and score posting to game center, the challenges work out of the box in iOS6, the user can always view the leader board - select a submitted score (or a completed achievement) and select "Challenge Friend".

**2** - The second way is to build a friend picker and let the user issue challenges within your game. But considering you're new to objective-c and game center, it's not so easy. But for your reference here is how you do it:

when you submit a GKScore object for the leaderboards - you can retain and use that GKScore object (call it myScoreObject) like this:

```
[myScoreObject issueChallengeToPlayers:selectedFriends message:yourMessage];
```

where selectedFriends is an NSArray (the friend picker should generate this) - the message is optional and can be used only if you want to send a message to challenged friends.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance, that has helped me sort it.  I was trying to run before I could walk.  A step back after reading this and it became clear.  Ta muchly!!!